# attribute binding to polymer template in swipe-pages

Tags: templates, binding, polymer

I am new to web development and I've hit a road block here with swipe-pages from https://github.com/TheSeamau5/swipe-pages

Basically, I want to make a "swipe-images" out of the "swipe-pages" by putting a template inside the contents of the swipe-pages. In other words, I want to pass to the polymer-element an array of strings (location of image) as attributes and the swipe-pages in the element should auto-generate swipe-pages with images inside it.

I am trying to avoid java script as much as I can and take advantage of polymer binding. I have even extended the template as a swipe-page.

here is the code so far and it does not work as expected. Is this approach correct or should I reinvent the swipe-pages uniquely for swipe-images. But nevertheless, the template binding should work!

```
<link rel="import" href="../swipe-pages-master/swipe-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../swipe-pages-master/swipe-page.html">

<polymer-element name="lesson-card-mini" attributes="items">
            <template>
                <style>
                    :host {
                        display: block;
                        position: relative;
                        padding: 0px;
                        width: 100%;
                    }
                    .content2 {
                        padding: 2px;
                        border: 1px solid #dedede;
                        border-top: none;
                        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                        background: black;
                    }
                </style>

                <div class="content2" style="width: auto; height: auto;"> 
                    <swipe-pages id="pgs" style="color: white;">
                        <template extends="swipe-page" repeat="{{item in items}}">               
                               <img src="{{item}}" style="width: 20px; height 20px"/>           
                        </template>
                    </swipe-pages>  
                </div>  

            </template>
            <script>
                Polymer('lesson-card-mini',
                        {
                            created: function() {

                            },
                            ready: function() {

                            },
                            toggle: function() {

                            }
                        });

            </script>
        </polymer-element>

    <polymer-element name="select-main">
        <template>
            <style>

            </style>

            <div vertical layout center center-justified>

                <lesson-card-mini style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
                                  items="['../images/01.png',
                                                     '../images/02.png',
                                                     '../images/03.png']"></lesson-card-mini>
            </div>

        </template>
        <script>

            Polymer('select-main',
            {

            });

        </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

Does anyone have a sample code on something like this?

Comment: I'm going to definitely try this code, but upon skimming through the code I was wondering, does it work if you do (in the top part) 

`<swipe-pages id="pgs" style="color:white">
   <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
     <swipe-page>
       <img src="{{item}}" style="width: 20px; height: 20px"/>  
     </swipe-page>
   </template>
 </swipe-pages>`

Comment: As in, not make the template extend swipe-page

Answer (score 1):

I made the change as mentioned and I got the code working. Turns out I did not initialise the array (attribute) in the polymer-element constructor and that was really important.

The below code works,.......... and now I have an "image swipe".

```
<link rel="import" href="../swipe-pages-master/swipe-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../swipe-pages-master/swipe-page.html">

<polymer-element name="lesson-card-mini" attributes="imglinks">
            <template>
                <style>
                    :host {
                        display: block;
                        position: relative;
                        padding: 0px;
                        width: 100%;
                    }
                    .content2 {
                        padding: 2px;
                        border: 1px solid #dedede;
                        border-top: none;
                        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                        background: black;
                    }
                </style>

                <div class="content2" style="width: auto; height: auto;"> 
                    <swipe-pages id="pgs" style="color: white;">
                        <template repeat="{{imglink in imglinks}}"> 
                            <swipe-page>
                                <img src="{{imglink}}" style="width: 20px; height: 20px"/>  
                            </swipe-page>          
                        </template>
                    </swipe-pages>
                </div>  

            </template>
            <script>
                Polymer('lesson-card-mini',
                        {
                            created: function() {
                                this.imglinks = []; // This line is important
                            },
                            ready: function() {

                            },
                            toggle: function() {

                            }
                        });

            </script>
        </polymer-element>

    <polymer-element name="select-main">
        <template>
            <style>

            </style>

            <div vertical layout center center-justified>

                <lesson-card-mini style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
                                  imglinks="['../images/01.png',
                                                     '../images/02.png',
                                                     '../images/03.png']"></lesson-card-mini>
            </div>

        </template>
        <script>

            Polymer('select-main',
            {

            });

        </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

With this, I could just have the pages up with an array of strings. Perhaps an improvement would be to have the page decipher the link to show image, videos, PDF files, text files etc by having a template selector. And if backed by auto-animation, can become an image carousel and slider too.

Thanks and hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! By the way, consider putting the imglinks attribute as a ["published" attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#published-properties)